# Programmatically Position Image on RDLC using Database Values

Tags: database, image, rdlc, pixel

I have an image that I'd like to programmatically position on an RDLC based on the X and Y values from the database. I originally thought I could just apply an expression to the Left and Top properties of the Location property, however it doesn't seem like there's an option to do that.

Is there anything I can do?

**EDIT:**

Fortunately the padding property allows expressions, however it seems I have another issue on my hands.

Here's my code for the "Left" property within the "Padding" property group.

```
=((Sum(Fields!intDessinX.Value, "dsRapport_uspReportCommandeInhumation") * 2.54) / 96) & "cm"
```

Essentially I'm converting the intDessinX value from the database from pixel to cm using the formula "cm = (pixel * 2.54) / 96" and finally appending "cm" to the end of the expression.

This does not work. I've done some research and can't seem to find how to take the value from a dataset and translate it into a measurement.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Mikael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!! Since we're developing the website in French we had previously set the culture to "fr-CA" and this causes the decimal character to be replaced by a comma character.

As such, when it came time for the reporting engine to evaluate the value (with the comma), it wasn't positioning my image as it simply didn't understand that the value was in fact numeric.